# How do i access/select a specific embedded document in mongoid?

Tags: mongoid, mongoid3

Is there a better way to do this?

```
class User
    embeds_many :groups

    def group(group_id)
        gid = Moped::BSON::ObjectId(group_id)
        self.groups.each.detect{|group| group.id == gid}
    end
end

class Group
    embedded_in :user
end
```

I am accessing the group in this way:

```
User.new.group(group_id)
```

If the user has 1000 embedded groups (hypothetically) then does that mean that i'll have to iterate through 1000 of them? Is there a better way to access a specific group?

Answer (score 2):

You can query the `groups` property of `User` just like a normal model. For example, if you want to find a specific `Group` by its id:

```
my_user.groups.find(group_id)
```

Querying with `where` is also possible:

```
my_user.groups.where(id: group_id).first
```